# Python Stack without using Pop function

Tags: python-2.7, stack

I am learning python and have an assignment to better my understanding of "class" and using "stack."

The requirements are as follows:

-Define a class which implements stack for numerical values.

-Cannot use built-in pop function

-Function push should check if value is numerical

-Function print_stack should print values in stack, most recent (on top) first

-Function IsEmpty should return True if stack is empty, false otherwise

Here is my work so far:

```
class stack():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def isEmpty(self):
        return (self.items == [])  #can also use return not self i think?

    def print_stack(self):
        print self.items
```

This is my very first class in programming so I'm sorry if my understanding is poor. I'm not looking for anyone to outright write this for me. I really want to understand how to go about this and receive some pointers on what I need to do as well as what I am lacking in understanding if it is obvious.

My questions are as follows:

1) How can I test if I am pushing a numerical value? On first thought, could I use try/except?

2) What is the best way to go about creating a pop function without using the one that's built in? This is really giving me a hard time. From my understanding I need to write something that will retrieve the last item from the list and return it.

3) to test my code would I do something like this?

```
test = stack()
test.push(1)
test.print_stack()
test.pop()  #whenever I learn how to make a pop function
test.isEmpty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How can I test if I am pushing a numerical value? On first thought, could I use try/except?**

You don't need to test it. Just convert it to int or whatever datatype you are working on at that point. for e.g.
if you are working with `int`

```
def push(self, item):
    self.items.append(int(item))
```

if you are working with `float`

```
def push(self, item):
    self.items.append(float(item))
```

if you are working with `string`

```
def push(self, item):
    self.items.append(str(item))
```

**What is the best way to go about creating a pop function without using the one that's built in? This is really giving me a hard time. From my understanding I need to write something that will retrieve the last item from the list and return it.**

There are multiple ways,

1. use `del`

   ```
   def pop(self):
       n = self.items[0]
       del self.items[0]
       return n
   ```
2. use slicing

   ```
   def pop(self):
       n = self.items[0]
       self.items = self.items[1:]
       return n
   ```

   *note that this would return a subset of the original but not modify it.*
3. use `popleft()`

   ```
   def pop(self):
       return self.items.popleft()
   ```

One suggestion
You can also use `len()` to check length of your list and use it to check whether stack is empty or not,

```
def isEmpty(self):
    return (len(self.items) == 0)
```

Note: before popping use your `isEmpty()` function to check if stack is empty.

**to test my code would I do something like this ?**

just try executing every function, If you think that there is a problem then print stack after every operation. you will see how exactly values are getting updated in the stack.

Comment: For some reason I forgot to upvote and accept this. Sorry @Ani

Comment: I am glad I could answer your question :)